# Remote wakeup of Proxy Server

Tags: windows-xp, networking, proxy, network-adapter

I have a Windows XP box running a proxy server (Proxy+), and I have a Linux box that connects to the internet through this proxy.  I have the Windows box configured to wake on lan by configuring the network card in Device Manager by checking "Allow this device to bring the computer out of standby.)  I have Standby enabled on Windows, but not Hibernate.

When I start up my browser on the Linux box (Firefox specifically), sometimes the Windows XP box is brought out of standby, sometimes it is not and I have to push the power button to manually bring it out of standby.  Sometimes the Windows box will go in standby before the 1 hour of inactivity I specified (on the order of 10-15 minutes).

Are there any other configurations I need to make on the Windows side?  Or, is there a way I can guarantee that the Linux machine wakes up the Windows box?

I should note that I have S3 Power management configured in BIOS.  Windows Machine is Dell Optiplex 240GX.  Linux is Dell Optiplex 270GX running OpenSuSE 11.2.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the XP machine with it's standby settings then you will need a Wake up on LAN implementation or an ILO box.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN
not ALL cards are capable of Wak up on LAN and ILO can be costly(very)

You can always disable standby on the XP machine via control panel->power

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I believe my machine has WAL enabled, it just behaves inconsistently.